# The name 'sr' doesn't exist in current context

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, try-catch, scope

I was following example from microsoft [site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx) for reading from text file. They say to do it like this:

```
class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"));
            {
                String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

but when I do it like that in Visual C# 2010 it brings me errors:

> Possible mistaken empty statement
>
> The name 'sr' does not exist in current context

I removed the `using` part and now the code looks like this and is working:

```
try
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt");
    string line = sr.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Why is that?

**Update:** there was semicolon at the end of `using(....);`

Comment: Your code if fine with using. Maybe you put `;` after using statement;

Comment: THe code looks correct. 
Do you have more code using sr variable after the Try/Catch?. If you are using sr outside then the variable is not defined. PD: Ok I understood it the other way, I thought the first code piece were working and not the second. Sorry

Comment: check for semicolons at the end of your using statement

Comment: the semicolon was the reason, and the small window

Comment: what's the difference between using( StreamReader ....) {} and just STreamReader....?

Comment: @cikatomo: See my answer for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm only adding this answer because the existing ones (while properly upvoted) just tell you what the error is, not WHY it's an error.

Doing this;

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"));
{
     String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
     Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

is actually the same (semantically) as doing this:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
{
    // Note that we're not doing anything in here
}
{
     String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
     Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

The second block (created by the second set of curly braces) doesn't have anything to do with the `using` block. Since a variable defined within a `using` block is only in scope within that block, it doesn't exist (in terms of being in scope and accessible) once your code reaches the second block.

You should use the `using` statement because `StreamReader` implements `IDisposable`. The `using` block provides a simple, clean way to ensure that--even in the case of an exception--your resources are properly cleaned up. For more information on the `using` block (and, specifically, what the `IDisposable` interface is), see the [meta description on the `IDisposable` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/idisposable/info).

Answer (score 14):

What you described is achieved by putting `;` after using statement

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"));
{
     String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
     Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Possibly you even didn't notice that and deleted later.

*What's the difference between using(StreamReader) and just StreamReader?*

When you put disposable variable (StreamReader) in using statement it's the same as:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt");
try
{
    String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
finally
{
    // this block will be called even if exception occurs
    if (sr != null)
        sr.Dispose(); // same as sr.Close();
}
```

Also if you declare variable in using block, it will be visible only in using block. Thats why `;` made your StreamReader non-existing in latter context. If you declare `sr` before using block, it will be visible later, but stream will be closed.

Comment: what's the difference between using( StreamReader ....) {} and just StreamReader... ?

Comment: using (StreamReader sr...) {} cleans up the "sr" object immediately after the closing brace. In the other approach you should ensure you dispose of the object properly when no longer used.

Comment: `using` statement automatically calls `Dispose` method on disposable objects declared in this statement. When you declare `StreamReader` in using statement - stream will be closed. And `using` closes stream properly (even in case of exception).

Answer (score 2):

change this:

```
  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"));
```

to this:

```
  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
```